Is it true that the interval between two points at constant rapidity/velocity from two different hyperbolas/proper accelerations is constant?
I'm not sure I heard the professor right, but when we have two hyperbolas (each for two different constant proper accelerations)
$$(x-x_0)^2-c^2(t-t_0)^2=\ell^2\equiv\frac{c^4}{\alpha^2}$$
and
$$(x-x_0)^2-c^2(t-t_0)^2=(\ell+\mathrm d\ell)^2,$$
then, the points from each hyperbola at the same rapidity $\phi$, that is, at the same speed $u$, have a constant separation $\mathrm d\ell$ in their inertial reference frame. I think this is related to Bell's spaceship paradox. If that's true or I interpreted it somewhat right, could someone provide a proof?
The only thing I know is that hyperbolas preserve the interval, in other words,
$$-(\Delta x^0)^2+(\Delta x)^2=-(\Delta x^{0'})^2+(\Delta x')^2.$$
This implies that they intersect on a point on the axis $x$ with the same length as it intersects at axis $x'$ (same goes for temporal axis). And I also know that the points with the same velocity are described by the intersection of $x^0=\dfrac{u}{c}x$ with an hyperbola. I mean it kind of makes sense because the $x^{0'}$ axis is tangent to the hyperbolic trajectory whilst this line that joins both points with equal velocity would act as the $x'$ axis.

The Euclidean analogue of your question concerns the difference between two radii along a common radial line.
